# Checking heteroscedasticity in arima residuals

Tags: r, arima

I'm using `auto.arima` function to analyze my data. And here's what I get:

```
Series: data 
ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2   drift
      1.6679  -0.8005  -1.2424  0.3125  0.4225
s.e.  0.1007   0.1107   0.1396  0.1413  0.1895

sigma^2 estimated as 17.34:  log likelihood=-438.37
AIC=888.73   AICc=889.3   BIC=906.99
```

I'm trying to perform a heteroscedastic test to my residual model using bptest from `lmtest` package with this code:

```
> bp<-bptest(lm(residuals(model)~1))
> bp

    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  lm(residuals(model) ~ 1)
BP = 1.231e-30, df = 0, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Am I doing `bptest` right? When I analyze another data with this code I always get the same `df` and `p-value`.

**edit:**
here is the data :

```
    World_Oil_Prices
[1-10] [11-20] [21-30] [31-40] [41-50] [51-60] [61-70] [71-80] [81-90] [91-100] [101-110] [111-120] [121-130] [131-140] [141-150] [151-156]
17.79   22.25   18.73   12.72   16.12   27.49   25.95   18.69   28.28   28.59   37.63   48.75   59.67   53.53   75.91   131.22
17.69   23.51   20.12   12.49   16.24   23.45   27.24   18.52   27.53   29.68   35.54   46.00   54.17   57.22   81.27   121.87
19.46   23.29   19.16   13.80   18.75   27.23   25.02   19.15   24.79   26.88   37.93   43.67   56.63   50.14   90.54   96.85
20.78   20.54   17.24   13.26   20.21   29.62   25.66   19.98   27.89   29.01   42.08   52.55   66.85   54.46   89.76   69.16
19.12   19.42   15.07   11.88   22.37   28.16   27.55   23.64   30.77   29.12   41.65   52.24   63.49   57.78   85.53   46.03
18.56   17.98   14.18   10.41   22.19   29.41   26.97   25.43   32.88   29.95   46.87   58.74   62.26   63.25   93.51   38.60
19.56   19.47   13.24   11.32   24.22   32.08   24.80   25.69   30.36   31.40   42.23   58.20   68.08   66.75   99.32   
20.19   18.02   13.39   10.75   25.01   31.40   25.81   24.49   25.49   31.32   39.09   53.32   66.45   68.29   111.03  
22.14   18.45   13.97   12.86   25.21   32.33   25.03   25.75   26.06   33.67   42.76   49.41   56.38   73.69   123.35  
23.43   18.79   12.48   15.73   27.15   25.28   20.73   26.78   27.91   33.71   44.35   51.66   53.58   67.10   128.33
```

And this is the R code:

```
library(forecast)
model<-auto.arima(data)
model
library(lmtest)
bp<-bptest(lm(residuals(model)~1))
bp
```

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152919/breusch-pagan-test-for-arima-model-in-r) post and the answer to it can be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy. So if I'm not using xreg in my arima model, is it right to use `bp<-bptest(lm(residuals(model)~1))` code?

Comment: I do not know the mechanics of the BP test well enough and I did not have time to dig into it yet, so I cannot answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that your model is possibly over-parameterized or over-differenced or both. This is the result of selecting from a set of fixed models and or the total ignoring of the effect of Pulses/Level Shifts/Seasonal Pulses/Local Time Trends. If you post your original data and your residual series I will test the constancy of the error variance by employing a search scheme along the lines suggested by TSAY http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf . Ignored by many researchers except a few since the mainstream time series software developers found it too difficult/technical to implement. Note that if the parameters of the model change over time this is often misdiagnosed as "evidence" of variance change. One needs to carefully diagnose possible Gauussian Violations.

Comment: no matter what data I use, it still show the same result if I use `bp<-bptest(lm(residuals(model)~1))` code.. Am I wrong in using this R code? Do u know another way to test heteroscedasticity in arima residuals by using R?

Comment: I mean it always show `df = 0` and `p-value < 2.2e-16` no matter what model I use

Comment: I can't precisely answer that question although clues might be forthcoming from a review of the data that you are using. That also might not be fruitful as you are saying that this phenomena also occurs for all data submitted by you.

Comment: I've edited my question to add the data.. I think I have problems in using `bptest` function. But I don't know what..

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at the essentials of the BP test, it does not seem suitable to use a model of the form `lm(resid~1)` as an argument to the `bptest` function. The idea of the BP test is that error variance may vary together with an explanatory variable. That variable cannot be identically equal to a constant, otherwise the error variance could not vary *with* it. So having `1` on the right hand side of `resid~1` does not make sense to me.

If you have an ARIMA model, you should perhaps follow the advice of @javlacalle [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152919/breusch-pagan-test-for-arima-model-in-r).
You should construct the variables corresponding to the AR(1), AR(2), MA(1) and MA(2) terms, say, $x_{t-1}$, $x_{t-2}$, $\varepsilon_{t-1}$, $\varepsilon_{t-2}$. Then build a model

$$\varepsilon_t^2=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{t-1}+\beta_2 x_{t-2}+\beta_3 \varepsilon_{t-1}+\beta_4 \varepsilon_{t-2}+u_t$$

and test the model's overall significance (normally reported as $F$-statistic in model summary).
If the model is insignificant ($F$-statistic relatively low, associated $p$-value relatively high), there is not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis "no conditional heteroskedasticity".
If the model is significant ($F$-statistic relatively high, associated $p$-value relatively low), the null hypothesis can be rejected in favour of the alternative hypothesis "presence of conditional heteroskedasticity".

I do not know the BP test very well and I do not remember ever seeing the BP test applied on residuals from an ARIMA model, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation.  Can you give me some suggestion about another test than can applied on residuals of arima model?

Comment: It is perhaps more popular to look for conditional heteroskedasticity of ARCH/GARCH type in the residuals of ARIMA models. ARCH-LM test can be used for that. In R, function `ArchTest` from package "FinTS" does that, for example.